# On Multiple click events within Div return as one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in a bit of a bind.
I have multiple cards.. with several click events possible (7) to be exact inside of each card.

I've added the same class to them all (each click event) with data tags that return different values.

Basically, I want to track all click events (7) at different times and check them as one per card.

If the user does anything within the card at all, count it as one event.. I am basically trying to count the views per card.

Right now I have something like this

```
 $(document).on("click", ".test", function() {
    console.log('Testing Stats View capture');
    var that = $(this);
    var testStats = that.data('capture-stats');
    console.log(testStats);   
 }));
```

Comment: 7 different click event handlers on one element is a code smell. Why are you doing this - I'm certain there's a better way to achieve your goal which will also avoid the need to address the issue in your question. If you could edit the question to include a more complete example, then we can offer more assistance

Comment: Without seeing HTML, I read this as 7 click events on 7 different cards  *"add class to them all*" and "*count the views per card*"  with one handler (code and "*check them as one*")- but the *"I have **a** card*" conflicts this.

Answer (score 1):

> count views per card

You can store the count on each card using `this.data()`:

```js
 $(document).on("click", ".card", function() {
 
     var clickcount = $(this).data("clickcount") || 0;
     clickcount++;
     $(this).data("clickcount", clickcount);
     
     console.log($(this).text() + " clicked: " + clickcount); 
     
 });
```

```css
.card { cursor: pointer; user-select: none;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='card'>card 1</div>
<div class='card'>card 2</div>
<div class='card'>card 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a data attribute to the element triggering the event, at the end of your handler, and check its presence at the beginning, as a condition to perform a given logic:

```js
 $(document).on("click", ".test", function() {
    console.log('Testing Stats View capture');
    var that = $(this);
 
    //if the prop data-event-triggered is not set yet for this element
    if ( !that.data('event-triggered') ){
      var testStats = that.data('capture-stats');
      //adds the prop data-event-triggered for this element
      that.data('event-triggered','true');
      console.log('event triggered-${testStats}');   
    }    
 });
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test" data-capture-stats="1">1</div>

<div class="test" data-capture-stats="2">2</div>
```